# query between two date fields and two entered dates

Tags: sql

I have the following Issue:

if user for example enter employee vacation period of three days starts for example `29/04/2017` ends `02/05/2017` (date return to office)
at the same time the employee requested the vacation has already a vacation stored in the table Empvacation (field Startdate `01/05/2017` & field EndDate `04/05/2017`
what I want is a query that gets of the entered vacation interferes (means don't want the user to put any dates that was used before the stored ones
I tried the following and works fine

this query works very well with any used dates 
like

```
28/04/2017 to 02/05/2017 query shows the date used (01/05/2017 to 04/05/2014)

29/04/2017 to 03/05/2017 query shows the date used (01/05/2017 to 04/05/2014)

01/05/2017 to 02/05/2017 query shows the date used (01/05/2017 to 04/05/2014)

02/05/2017 to 04/05/2017 query shows the date used (01/05/2017 to 04/05/2014)

01/05/2017 to 03/05/2017 query shows the date used (01/05/2017 to 04/05/2014)

01/05/2017 to 04/05/2017 query shows the date used (01/05/2017 to 04/05/2014)
```

but if the user enter a date like

02/05/2017 to 03/05/2017

query shows nothing and the vacation will be accepted which is in fact not allowed cause the employee already in a vacation

the query I use

```
SELECT TblEmpVacation.*, TblVacations.VacationName, tblEmployees.Emp_Name, TblEmpVacation.DateStart, TblEmpVacation.DateEnd
FROM tblEmployees INNER JOIN (TblVacations INNER JOIN TblEmpVacation ON TblVacations.VacationCode = TblEmpVacation.VacationNO) ON tblEmployees.Emp_ID = TblEmpVacation.EmpNo 
WHERE tblEmployees.Emp_Name="Khaled Eissa" AND TblEmpVacation.DateStart Between 5/2/2017 And 5/3/2017 AND TblEmpVacation.DateStart<>5/2/2017
 UNION 
SELECT TblEmpVacation.*, TblVacations.VacationName, tblEmployees.Emp_Name, TblEmpVacation.DateStart, TblEmpVacation.DateEnd
FROM tblEmployees INNER JOIN (TblVacations INNER JOIN TblEmpVacation ON TblVacations.VacationCode = TblEmpVacation.VacationNO) ON tblEmployees.Emp_ID = TblEmpVacation.EmpNo
WHERE tblEmployees.Emp_Name="Khaled Eissa" AND TblEmpVacation.DateEnd Between  5/2/2017   And 5/3/2017 AND TblEmpVacation.DateEnd<>5/3/2017
```

any help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPFDx.png)

Comment: No idea what your question is.  What is your question?

Comment: i think you may need to use `to_char` method to convert string to date in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: see edited question and have a look to the tables pic

Comment: Print out the content of `QueryRS.Source` to the console (or use the debugger to display it's content), copy the content into an sql sheet, execute it and maybe the dbms gives you a hint.

Comment: Pons : the fields are date/time field

Comment: @StephanLechner thanks for the advice, already done pls check it now

Comment: @Pons can you check it again and please adjust the code

Answer (score 0):

here is what I had to do just in case any one might face the same problem

since all dates can be captured by the above query 
except those who comes in between datestart & dateend

so after excuting the above query I had to excute the following:

```
SELECT TblEmpVacation.*, TblVacations.VacationName, tblEmployees.Emp_Name, TblEmpVacation.DateStart, TblEmpVacation.DateEnd
FROM (tblEmployees INNER JOIN TblEmpVacation ON tblEmployees.Emp_ID = TblEmpVacation.EmpNo) INNER JOIN TblVacations ON TblEmpVacation.VacationNO = TblVacations.VacationCode
WHERE (((tblEmployees.Emp_Name)="Khaled Eissa") AND ((TblEmpVacation.DateStart)<#5/2/2017#) AND ((TblEmpVacation.DateEnd)>#5/3/2017#));
```

that is what I had to do unless otherwise you guys have a very advance query can be done

thanks any how